# Night lights in qgis

Tags: qgis

I am having trouble finding resources for night lights layers for use in QGis. It seems these are available for ArcGis ([Earth at Night Package](http://esri.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b3824432e4204db69ed48552c8c3b81f)), but unfortunately I don't have access to this and can't find a way of transferring ESRI packages into a form usable by QGis. Are there any packages or tutorials about for loading night light images into QGis?

Comment: did you try this: https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/data/web_data/v4composites/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download nighttime lights images at EOG website [here](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/viirs/download_dnb_composites.html). However, these come from VIIRS DNB. For DMSP-OLS, check this [site](https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html). You can import obtained GeoTIFFs to QGIS as you would do with similar satellite images.

Comment: I guess the part that I am lost on is importing a GeoTIFF so that I can overlay other vector layers

Comment: you can just drag and drop the file into the QGIS window ...

Comment: Or check out [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html) simple tutorial to see how to import them and mosaic into one image.